# bash sed replace text in between two special characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to create a job that will require replacing a variable on two lines:

```
hosts: all-qa1:&load_balanced_servers
hosts: all-qa1:!load_balanced_servers
```

I will only need to replace everything after `-` and before `:`.

It will be replaced with strings like `qa`, `qa1`, `qa2`, staging, production etc.

Comment: need more information, expected output ?

Comment: so the job will take in a variable will replace whatever is inbetween - and : in this case REPLACE=qa1 but REPLACE will constantly change

Comment: replace with what string?

Comment: anything in between these two special character "-REPLACE:" in this example its -qa1:

Comment: May be: `sed -E "s/-([^:]+):/-$var:/" file`

Comment: no luck with that command @anubhava

Comment: when i ran it on the command line to test without -E, i didn't see any updates made to the qa1 string in the output

Comment: See this command working here: https://ideone.com/rINBN

Comment: `sed "s/-[^:]*:/-$var:/" file` may also work.

Comment: that last command works perfectly! @anubhava can you post this an answer to this question please? Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this simple `sed` command:

```
sed "s/-[^:]*:/-$var:/" file
```

or else:

```
sed -E "s/-([^:]+):/-$var:/" file
```

[Code Demo](https://ideone.com/rINBN)